# Recursion - clean code vs performance

Tags: performance, recursion, readability

I have a small conflict between writing a clean code vs. performance overhead.

Assuming I'm scanning a NxN array, using a recursion in JAVA, and my only stopping condition is stay in the array boundary.

I can write the function as follow, which is more clean and readable:

```
private void move(int x, int y){
    if(outOfBound(x,y)){ \\ stopping condition
        return;
    }

    move(x+1, y);
    move(x, y+1);
    move(x-1, y);
    move(x, y-1);
}
```

Or I can write it as follow:

```
private void move(int x, int y){
    if(!outOfBound(x+1,y)){ \\ stopping condition
        move(x+1, y);
    }
    if(!outOfBound(x,y+1)){ \\ stopping condition
        move(x, y+1);
    }
    if(!outOfBound(x-1,y)){ \\ stopping condition
        move(x-1, y);
    }
    if(!outOfBound(x,y-1)){ \\ stopping condition
        move(x, y-1);
    }
}
```

Which, as far as I know, can save 4N recursive calls (4N new stack frames).

So, would it be 'more correct' to write the second function in order to avoid unnecessary calls?

Comment: 1) You're missing some `not`s if the two versions are supposed to be equivalent.  2) Why do you think your second version saves any calls?  Since `x` and `y` are invariant through a given level of the recursion, `isCondition(x,y)` should yield the same result in all four cases, and the recursive calls either happen or do not happen together as a set.  Version 1 is cleaner and avoids the redundant calls to `isCondition`.

Comment: - Unless of course the result of subsequent `isCondition` calls do depend on the calls to `move`, in which case the logic of version 1 would be incorrect anyway.

Comment: @pjs, it was a mistake, I edited the second function. hope it is clear now.

Comment: It would be more correct to write it in the most readable way. If it becomes a performance issue, you can profile it and change it later.

Comment: I don't think you'll have a performance issue since in the event it is out of bound the call is `O(1)` space and time complexity and you are after the ones where it is higher.. In the cases where it continues which will be your problem, not when it terminates.

Comment: "clean code vs performance" - clean code. Alter the code only **after** you profile it and prove that you have a performance issue (not likely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way to solve this dilemma - measure the performance in actual project context.

If this is seriously affecting performance in real life scenarios, and becoming a bottleneck, by all means change it to the less optimal one.

On the other hand, if it is not really making a difference in overall performance of your app, let it be cleaner. One bug introduced because of dirty code can cost you much more in pure dollar terms than the server costs associated to the code being slightly dirtier.